# The best solution for the main thread to obtain data in the coroutine to avoid null values?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following code, in the click event I need to use the class that is queried from the database.

```kotlin
data class Work(...)

fun Compose(){
    var work1: Work? = null
    var work2: Work? = null
    var work3: Work? = null

    LaunchedEffect(true){
        CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
            work1 = workViewModel.getById(1)
            work2 = workViewModel.getById(2)
            work3 = workViewModel.getById(3)
        }
    }

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
        .clickable(onClick = {
            val url = "https://www.google.com/"
                                
            when{
                url.contains(work1?.baseUrl) -> {...}
                url.contains(work2?.baseUrl) -> {...}
                url.contains(work3?.baseUrl) -> {...}
            }
        })       
    ){}

}
```

this creates a problem, `work3?.baseUrl` found String? type Required CharSequence type.

So far it seems that only the `!!` operator can successfully run this code. But this code is based on a database query, using the `!!` operator is very risky.

And if you add a null operator before this, also not working.

```kotlin
    requireNotNull(work1)  

    when{
        url.contains(work1.baseUrl) -> {...}
    }
```

> Smart cast to 'Work' is impossible, because 'work1' is a local variable that is captured by a changing closure

Can you tell me what is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not having that logic in the Composable. Try to move that to a function in the ViewModel, something like:

```
private val url = "https://www.google.com/"

fun validateBaseUrl() {
  viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            workViewModel.getById(1)?.let {
               if (url.contains(it)) { .. }
            }
            work2 = workViewModel.getById(2)?.let {
               if (url.contains(it)) { .. }
            }
            work3 = workViewModel.getById(3)?.let {
               if (url.contains(it)) { .. }
            }
  }

}
```

And then in the Composable would be something like:

```
fun Compose() {
   Card(
        modifier = Modifier
        .clickable(onClick = { viewModel.validateBaseUrl() })       
    ){}
}
```

Remember to use the State Hoisting instead of sending the view model through the Composables.

Finally, you would need to send back a State to the Composable, either using a LiveData or a StateFlow.

Comment: The logic should indeed be in the `ViewModel` but with your solution it would retrieve all work objects from the db with each call to onClick. I don't think that's what the OP wants (retrieve once and then verify against the once retrieved work objects).

Comment: The click event will be triggered frequently. If so, the database will be queried every time it is clicked, and this IO operation is actually unnecessary.

Comment: That's right. In that case, you could load the work1 .. workN as soon as the View Model is created, instead of having that in the Composable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a scope for the `work` properties :

```
work1?.run { url.contains(baseUrl) } == true -> {...}
```

Within the `run` lambda the accessed object is immutable even if the work properties themselves are mutable.
The `== true` is needed because the left side of the comparison operator can be either a Boolean or null.

You could also define an extension function like this:

```
fun Work?.isContainedIn(url: String) = this?.run { url.contains(baseUrl) } == true
```

and then just do:

```
work1.isContainedIn(url) -> { }
work2.isContainedIn(url) -> { }
work3.isContainedIn(url) -> { }
```

Comment: Here is a solution. Regarding the null value, it can only be handled according to the code I wrote?

Comment: @FreedomFoolt I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Because the IO operation of the android mechanism cannot be placed on the main thread, I first created a variable and assigned it to be empty, and used a coroutine. If there is a way I don't have to create a null value, then the complexity of the code is reduced a lot.